# How did "tot" come to mean a measure or ration?

Tags: etymology, pirate-english

How did [tot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tot#Noun),

> A measure of spirits, especially rum.

get that meaning?

It seems to have come to mean a specific ration, as in the daily *tot* of rum given to a sailor in the Royal Navy (well, no longer daily; see [Black Tot Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Tot_Day)).

This is in almost complete opposition to the idea of a *total*, though I can see how perhaps you could [tot up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tot_up) the tots to make a whole. Other possibilities might be an association with the *small child* meaning of *tot* (something tiny) or [totter](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=totter) (stumbling).

(I'm also curious about *teetotal*, but it looks as though it came later, so it's unlikely to be a source for this meaning.)

Comment: I believe *teetotal* is unrelated, coming from "T for 'total abstainer' in the temperance society records".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OED has for "tot" 4:

1a.  A very small or tiny child.

'2.  A very small drinking-vessel; a child's mug. (See also quot. 1845.) Chiefly dial.

'3. A minute quantity of anything, esp. of drink; a dram; also, anything very small.

[Quotes inserted because otherwise stackexchange replaces my '2' and '3' with '1' and '2'].

So the implication is that it comes from the "small child" meaning. The OED does not have an origin for that use.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tot):

> **tot (2)**
>   "to reckon up," 1760, from *tot* (n.), first recorded 1680s,
>   short for *total*.

Etymology references from [Memidex](http://www.memidex.com/tot+small-indefinite-quantity):

- **New World Dictionary**:
  tot | totted [past tense] | totting [present participle] 
  Origin: probably from Scandinavian, as in Old Norse *tuttr*, small chap, *tutta*, little girl | contraction from "total"
  [www.yourdictionary.com/tot](http://www.yourdictionary.com/tot)

  tot
  Origin: probably from Scandinavian, as in Old Norse *tuttr*, small chap, *tutta*, little girl
  [www.yourdictionary.com/totted](http://www.yourdictionary.com/totted)
- **American Heritage Dictionary**:
  tot | totted [past tense] | totting [present participle] | tots [3rd-person singular present]
  Origin: unknown
  [www.yourdictionary.com/tot](http://www.yourdictionary.com/tot)
- **Oxford Dictionary**:
  tot [entry 1]
  First use: early 18th century
  Origin: (originally dialect): of unknown origin
  [oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tot](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tot)

  tot [entry 2] | totted [past tense] | totting [present participle] | tots [3rd-person singular present]
  First use: mid 18th century
  Origin: archaic *tot* "set of figures to be added up", abbreviation of "total" or of Latin *totum* "the whole"
  [oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tot--2](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tot--2)

  tot [entry 3] | totted [past tense] | totting [present participle] | tots [3rd-person singular present]
  First use: late 19th century
  Origin: slang tot "bone", of unknown origin
  [oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tot--3](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tot--3)
- **Merriam-Webster**:
  tot [entry 1, noun]
  First use: 1725
  Origin: unknown
  [www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tot)

  tot [entry 2, verb, abbreviation] | totted [past tense] | totting [present participle]
  First use: about 1772
  Origin: *tot*., abbreviation of *total*
  [www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tot show=1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tot%20show=1)
- **Encarta Dictionary**:
  tot [entry 2] | totted [past tense] | totting [present participle] | tots [3rd-person singular present]
  First use: Mid-18th century
  Origin: Shortening of total, or from Latin *tot* "this number, so many"
  [encarta.msn.com/dictionary 701710519/definition.html](http://encarta.msn.com/dictionary%20701710519/definition.html)

Comment: Is there anywhere at all in this long answer where you address the question?